# Paste Values in Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Hello I have been trying to use the [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx) paste values on another sheet but every thing I've tried I keep receiving the same error.

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

```
xl.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
xl.Workbook wb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
xl.Worksheet data = wb.Sheets["Data"];
xl.Worksheet datasheet = wb.Sheets["DataSheet"];
xl.Worksheet pivot = wb.Sheets["Pivot"];
xl.Range dataRng = data.Range["A1:C" + 
      xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(data.Range["A:A"])];
xl.Range pivotRng = pivot.Range["A1"];

addPivot ap = new addPivot();
ap.DataRange = dataRng;
ap.DestRng = pivotRng;
ap.PivotSheet = pivot;
ap.createPivot("FullName","Date");

pivot.PivotTables("PivotTable1").NullString = "0";
pivot.UsedRange.Copy();   

datasheet.Range["A2:GT999"].ClearContents();  

datasheet.Range["A2"].PasteSpecial(xl.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, 
                                   xl.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, 
                                   System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);

datasheet.Range["2:2"].ClearContents();
```

I have Tried

```
datasheet.Range["A2"].PasteSpecial(xl.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues

datasheet.Range["A2"].PasteSpecial(xl.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, 
                                   xl.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone)
```

and what you see above.

thanks!

Comment: Is this a typo or what means this: datasheet.Range["2:2"].ClearContents(); 
It should be something like:
datasheet.Range["A2:A2"].ClearContents();

Comment: no that is correct, that clears the contents of the entire row 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `ClearContents` before the `Copy`.  Excel is removing your copied range (same as hitting `ESC` in the program) when you clear those cells out.  Then you are trying to `PasteSpecial` but nothing is in the clipboard any longer.

```
//...code above

datasheet.Range["A2:GT999"].ClearContents();  

pivot.UsedRange.Copy();

datasheet.Range["A2"].PasteSpecial(xl.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, 
                                   xl.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, 
                                   System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);                                   
//code below...
```

If you are debugging this step-by-step, you would see the dashed border around the copied range disappear after the `ClearContents` call.  Excel is a bit odd (but predictable) about when the copied range is forgotten.  Editing cells anywhere in the `Workbook` is one sure way to make it forget.